# i need to process it background

Tags: curl

[i need to process it background, but it's  not working, not posting the 'id' to process.php. what's the error?]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo7hX.png)

Comment: What is your question? Please refer to [ask].

Comment: post edited sir, picture added